# Javascript regular expression for validating a special string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am new to javascript regular expressions.Any-way i want to valiadate a string that matches some conditions

Here are  the conditions

1.String contains only 9 characters

2.First two letters must be alphabets.

3.third letter must be '-' this.

4.Remaining 6 letters must be digits

```
function validateInput(str){
   if(str.length>9){
    alert("Exeeds maximum limit");
  }
}
```

How can i do the rest of the validations using regex?

Comment: https://regex101.com is a nice place to test regexing

Comment: what did you tried till now? edit your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex matches exactly what you described:

```
 /^[a-z]{2}-\d{6}$/i
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC6bK6/1)</kbd>

- `^` matches the start of string (preventing matches in the middle of the string)
- `[a-z]{2}` matches 1 letter, repeated 2 times (thus it matches 2 letters).
- `-` matches a literal dash
- `\d{6}` matches a digit, repeated 6 times (6 digits).
- `$` matches the end of string.
- **Mode**: `/i` - case-insensitive match. So `[a-z]` also matches uppercase letters as well.

---

**Code**

```js
function validateInput(str){
    if(/^[a-z]{2}-\d{6}$/i.test(str)){
        document.body.innerText += str + "\t- Valid input\n";
    } else {
        document.body.innerText += str + "\t- Invalid input\n";
    }
}

validateInput("xY-123456");
validateInput("abc-12345");
```

<sup>Note: using `document.body.innerText` as a way to output in the Code Snippet, but it shouldn't be used in your code</sup>

Comment: You saved my time.Thanks a lot buddy:)